# Maven Failsafe Plugin not adding target/classes to classpath

Tags: java, maven, junit, classpath, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have the following default configuration for the Maven Failsafe Plugin:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-integration-test</id>
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>default-verify</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

The [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html) states that the default classpath includes both the `target/test-classes` and `target/classes` directories, in that order. However, when I run `mvn clean install` or `mvn integration-test`, I don't see the `classes` folder as part of the classpath. This is causing test failures as I am injecting a class from my source into the test and I get a `NoClassDefFound` exception.

Here is the verbose output:

> [DEBUG] test(compact) classpath:  test-classes  package.jar  javax.inject-1.jar  cdi-api-1.2.jar ...

As you can see the `classes` folder should have been added before the project dependencies, but it is not.

However, when I run the `mvn failsafe:integration-test` **goal** specifically, instead of a phase, then the classpath includes `classes` immediately after `test-classes` and the tests are successful, which is consistent with the documentation.

What am I not understanding about the build process? Why is the classpath different when running the phase as opposed to running the goal? How can I get `classes` in the classpath even when running the phase?

Comment: First I would suggest not to define the plugin configuration like that just do it as state in the [usage documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html) no own id's etc.. furthermore you see the entry in your debug out: `package.jar` ? What exactly is this? This is the code you have under `target/classes` as packaged in a jar file...BTW: Can you attach full log output of your build? Is there a good reason why you are using such an older version of surefire/failsafe plugin? BTW: Are you using the same version for surefire and failsafe plugin?

Comment: I am actually not defining it like that, that is what I copied from the effective-pom so I think Maven is adding those default IDs. I will look at the `package.jar`, I don't see that when I run the goal directly so maybe it could contain the source classes. But then I would wonder why I'm still getting the `NoClassDefFound` exception...?

Comment: Ah but you didn't wrote that...Yes the id's are added by default that's true. Can you show the code which causes the issues ? Or do you have a link on the whole project?

Comment: I looked in the `package.jar` and that just contains the server, no classes. Here is the project: https://github.com/OpenLiberty/draft-guide-arquillian-managed/tree/master/finish. I worked around the issue by adding the `additionalClasspathElements` config to the Failsafe plugin, but you should be able to replicate the issue if you remove that block.

Comment: The liberty-maven-plugin creates the `package.jar` which is if I correctly understand the wrong..I assume the liberty-maven-plugin should be configured differently...But I'm not sure cause I don't know liberty-maven-plugin...